# Change WP admin post status filter for custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-hook

How do you change/rename the text of post statuses in the top of the WP custom post type page

All | Published | Scheduled | Draft

Answer (score 8):

Using the filter `views_edit-{$post_type}`. Modify the array to set the desired post types:

```
foreach( array( 'post', 'portfolio' ) as $hook )
    add_filter( "views_edit-$hook", 'modified_views_so_15799171' );

function modified_views_so_15799171( $views ) 
{
    $views['all'] = str_replace( 'All ', 'Tutti ', $views['all'] );

    if( isset( $views['publish'] ) )
        $views['publish'] = str_replace( 'Published ', 'Online ', $views['publish'] );

    if( isset( $views['future'] ) )
        $views['future'] = str_replace( 'Scheduled ', 'Future ', $views['future'] );

    if( isset( $views['draft'] ) )
        $views['draft'] = str_replace( 'Drafts ', 'In progress ', $views['draft'] );

    if( isset( $views['trash'] ) )
        $views['trash'] = str_replace( 'Trash ', 'Dustbin ', $views['trash'] );

    return $views;
}
```

[image: preview]

Comment: may I ask you to have a look at a wordpress custom field related question here -  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43782429/wordpress-make-custom-field-values-clickable-to-retrive-them-later ?

Comment: Thanks for this useful answer, which helped me answering partially in [**this thread**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50549062/rename-multiple-order-statuses-in-woocommerce/50550058#50550058) related to Woocommerce orders *(`shop_order` custom post type)*.