# Rename multiple order statuses in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, orders

I'm trying to rename multiple WooCommerce order status by editing my theme's functions.php file. I found some code posted here a couple years ago that works to change a single order status, but since I'm very inexperienced with php, I don't know how to expand on it to change multiple statuses.  Ideally I'd  also like to rename 'wc-processing' to  'Paid' and 'wc-on-hold' to 'Pending'.

Here's the code I found to edit a single order status:

```
function wc_renaming_order_status( $order_statuses ) {
    foreach ( $order_statuses as $key => $status ) {
        $new_order_statuses[ $key ] = $status;
        if ( 'wc-completed' === $key ) {
            $order_statuses['wc-completed'] = _x( 'Order Received', 'Order status', 'woocommerce' );
        }
    }
    return $order_statuses;
}
add_filter( 'wc_order_statuses', 'wc_renaming_order_status' );
```

Anyone know what changes I need to make to change additional statuses?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As Pending order status exist, you need also to rename the existing "Pending" status. If not you will get 2 different statuses with the same "Pending" label.

First to rename those order statuses:

```
add_filter( 'wc_order_statuses', 'rename_order_statuses', 20, 1 );
function rename_order_statuses( $order_statuses ) {
    $order_statuses['wc-completed']  = _x( 'Order Received', 'Order status', 'woocommerce' );
    $order_statuses['wc-processing'] = _x( 'Paid', 'Order status', 'woocommerce' );
    $order_statuses['wc-on-hold']    = _x( 'Pending', 'Order status', 'woocommerce' );
    $order_statuses['wc-pending']    = _x( 'Waiting', 'Order status', 'woocommerce' );

    return $order_statuses;
}
```

And Also in the bulk edit order list dropdown:

```
add_filter( 'bulk_actions-edit-shop_order', 'custom_dropdown_bulk_actions_shop_order', 20, 1 );
function custom_dropdown_bulk_actions_shop_order( $actions ) {
    $actions['mark_processing'] = __( 'Mark paid', 'woocommerce' );
    $actions['mark_on-hold']    = __( 'Mark pending', 'woocommerce' );
    $actions['mark_completed']  = __( 'Mark order received', 'woocommerce' );

    return $actions;
}
```

[image]

And also this is needed (for the top menu):

```
foreach( array( 'post', 'shop_order' ) as $hook )
    add_filter( "views_edit-$hook", 'shop_order_modified_views' );

function shop_order_modified_views( $views ){
    if( isset( $views['wc-completed'] ) )
        $views['wc-completed'] = str_replace( 'Completed', __( 'Order Received', 'woocommerce'), $views['wc-completed'] );

    if( isset( $views['wc-processing'] ) )
        $views['wc-processing'] = str_replace( 'Processing', __( 'Paid', 'woocommerce'), $views['wc-processing'] );

    if( isset( $views['wc-on-hold'] ) )
        $views['wc-on-hold'] = str_replace( 'On hold', __( 'Pending', 'woocommerce'), $views['wc-on-hold'] );

    if( isset( $views['wc-pending'] ) )
        $views['wc-pending'] = str_replace( 'Pending', __( 'Stucked', 'woocommerce'), $views['wc-pending'] );

    return $views;
}
```

*(Thanks to [brasofilo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1287812/brasofilo) : [Change WP admin post status filter for custom post type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15799171/change-wp-admin-post-status-filter-for-custom-post-type/15799816#15799816))*

[image]

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

> Since Woocommerce 3.3 to handle the preview popup (eye symbol) in admin order list:
>
> [Replace order status names everywhere incl. Woocommerce admin order preview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54297649/replace-order-status-names-everywhere-incl-woocommerce-admin-order-preview/54298389#54298389)

Comment: This works really well. However if the string has been translated, the "sub menu" (ul.subsubsub) uses the translated string instead of the newly assigned string.

Comment: @PatrikAlienus This depends on many things (like if when use a plugin for translations)…

Comment: I'm not using a plugin for translating it, just the .mo files in the language directory.

Comment: @PatrikAlienus you can try by increasing the hook priority like: `add_filter( "views_edit-$hook", 'shop_order_modified_views', 1000 );`

Comment: @LoicTheAztec Everything works fine for me except the code for the top menu. I have woocommerce 6.8. Maybe something has changed?

Comment: @Nerea Hey there! I'm a bit late to the party, but yes - you are right - something has changed. Please refer to this answer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77417715/7020946)