# Filtering orders list in WooCommerce with HPOS

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, orders

I'm in the process of converting an open source plugin to be HPOS-compatible. One of its features is additional filters on the orders list in admin (inline with the order statuses), eg:
[image: example]

I can't seem to actually execute the modification of the query. Previously, I was hooking into `pre_get_posts` which obviously is no longer relevant when WP_Post is no longer being used.

<strike>Then the same for a filter field, for which I was hooking into `restrict_manage_posts`.</strike> *found the equivalent hook: `woocommerce_order_list_table_restrict_manage_orders`*

Anyone have an idea which hook to use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On [High-Performance Order Storage](https://woocommerce.com/document/high-performance-order-storage/) documentation, there is a link to [High Performance Order Storage Upgrade Recipe Book](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/High-Performance-Order-Storage-Upgrade-Recipe-Book) where you will find the path(s) to related core files you are looking for.

In this documentation, you have:

```
use Automattic\WooCommerce\Internal\DataStores\Orders\CustomOrdersTableController;
```

that points to `woocommerce/src/Internal/DataStores/Orders`, where [`OrdersTableQuery.php` file](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/release/8.2/plugins/woocommerce/src/Internal/DataStores/Orders/OrdersTableQuery.php) is the right location to look at.

Inside the method `maybe_override_query()` you have at line 233:

```
$pre_query = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_hpos_pre_query', null, $this, $this->sql );
```

Inside the method `build_query()` you have at line 877:

```
$clauses = (array) apply_filters_ref_array( 'woocommerce_orders_table_query_clauses', array( $pieces, &$this, $this->args ) );
```

And so on…

As `WC_Order_Query` is used to query orders for HPOS, the following filters should still work:

- `woocommerce_order_query_args` filter hook (replaces `pre_get_posts`),
- `woocommerce_order_query` filter hook (replaces `pre_get_posts`),
- and may be try `woocommerce_order_data_store_cpt_get_orders_query` filter hook.

For `restrict_manage_posts` hook now you will use:
`woocommerce_order_list_table_restrict_manage_orders`

###### Some others replacements hooks with HPOS:

- To edit existing columns or add custom columns to admin Orders list:

  - `manage_woocommerce_page_wc-orders_columns` replaces the hook: 
    `manage_edit-shop_order_columns`
  - `manage_woocommerce_page_wc-orders_custom_column` replaces the hook: 
    `manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column`
- To make custom order metadata searchable in admin Order list use:

  - `woocommerce_order_table_search_query_meta_keys` replacing the hook: 
    `woocommerce_shop_order_search_fields`
- For Bulk actions in admin Orders list:

  - `bulk_actions-woocommerce_page_wc-orders` replaces the hook: 
    `bulk_actions-edit-shop_order`
  - `handle_bulk_actions-woocommerce_page_wc-orders` has 2 arguments `$column` and `$order` and replaces the hook
    `handle_bulk_actions-edit-shop_order`

Comment: `woocommerce_order_query_args` did the trick – thanks!

Comment: Very nice finding for `restrict_manage_posts` replacement hook located in ListTable.php file !

Comment: wc_get_order will not work in hpos mode ?

Comment: @developerme Yes of course it works… What does not work with HPOS is all related WP post and postmeta functions as WooCommerce uses custom database tables and caching.

Answer (score 6):

I originally commented with a question, but deleted it, because I was understanding the strike-through incorrectly. I though you wrote that `woocommerce_order_list_table_restrict_manage_orders` is the replacement hook for `pre_get_posts`.

For others with similar low reading comprehension, the updated hooks for the admin order page are:

| OLD | NEW |
| --- | --- |
| `pre_get_posts` | `woocommerce_order_query_args` |
| `restrict_manage_posts` | `woocommerce_order_list_table_restrict_manage_orders` |
| `manage_edit-shop_order_columns` | `manage_woocommerce_page_wc-orders_columns` |
| `manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column` | `manage_woocommerce_page_wc-orders_custom_column` |
| `bulk_actions-edit-shop_order` | `bulk_actions-woocommerce_page_wc-orders` |
| `handle_bulk_actions-edit-shop_order` | `handle_bulk_actions-woocommerce_page_wc-orders` |

I'v also included some others that I had a hard time locating, mostly because `get_current_screen()->id` has changed for the admin order table.

Answer (score 0):

If your filter should run only in orders list, consider using this hook to replace pre_get_posts:

```
woocommerce_shop_order_list_table_prepare_items_query_args
```

because it affects only queries in the list table, while `woocommerce_order_query_args` would have impact on all query orders on the site.

Here below a sample code:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_shop_order_list_table_prepare_items_query_args', 'my_custom_query_args');

function my_custom_query_args( $query_args ) {
$meta_query = array(
            array(
                'key'   => '_my_meta',
                'value' => 'my_value',
            )
        );

        $query_args['meta_query'] = array_merge(
            $query_args['meta_query'] ?? array(),
            $meta_query
        );

        return $query_args;
}
```