Admin orders custom sortable column in WooCommerce with HPOS
I recently upgraded a Woocommerce website to use HPOS and I found out the custom column sorting no longer works. In Woocommerce I setup a sortable column for a customers last name. I adjusted my code to use meta_query to sort orders based on _shipping_last_name but no results are returned. I have a column that shows the correct last name value, but the sort feature doesn't sort.
Here is the sorting code currently:
function hpos_args( $query_vars ) {

    if(isset($query_vars['orderby']) && $query_vars['orderby'] == 'customer_user'){
        $query_vars['meta_query'] = array(array(    'key' => '_shipping_last_name' ));
        $query_vars['orderby'] = array('meta_value' => $query_vars['order']);
    }

    return $query_vars;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_query_args', 'hpos_args', 10, 1 );

'customer_user' is the column title, the values in the column are the meta_value for _shipping_last_name

Search before posting your question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77366037/filtering-orders-list-in-woocommerce-with-hpos

That other question doesnt address filtering by the _shipping_last_name, I cant find info on that aspect of the question. I am using the woocommerce_order_query_args like that other question mentions.

@Snuffy OP already ask a question before that I marked as duplicated linked to https://stackoverflow.com/q/77366037/3730754 thread… But it doesn't help when trying to filter HPOS orders for the shipping last name, as it's now located in wp_wc_order_addresses DB table within 2 columns: address_type and last_name, so not anymore filterable as metadata.

@phpcoder _shipping_last_name metadata doesn't exist on HPOS orders, as  it's now located in wp_wc_order_addresses DB table within 2 columns: address_type and last_name, so not anymore filterable as metadata.

@LoicTheAztec so based on that info whats the best method to sort by last_name from the wp_wc_order_addresses table from within the woocommerce_order_query_args? or is there another method I should look into?

@phpcoder If you don't want to ruin performances from HPOS, you should save the "shipping last name" as custom order metadata on all existing orders, using a simple SQL query via PhpMyAdmin and implement some custom code for new orders. Then from there you can use this custom metadata key to filter your orders via woocommerce_order_query_args hook.

When you have only one meta key, simply use "meta_key" query argument instead.
Also, you need to target "customer_user" order_by  query string argument like:
// Define custom sortable column(s)
add_filter( "woocommerce_shop_order_list_table_sortable_columns", 'custom_admin_order_list_sortable_columns' );
function custom_admin_order_list_sortable_columns( $sortable_columns ) {
    $sortable_columns['customer_user'] = 'customer_user';

    return $customer_user;
}

// Alter the query for custom sortable column(s)
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_query_args', 'filter_admin_hpos_order_lists', 10, 1 );
function filter_admin_hpos_order_lists( $query_args ) {
    if ( isset($_GET['orderby']) && $_GET['orderby'] === 'customer_user' ) {
        $query_args['meta_key'] = '_sorting_name';
        $query_args['orderby'] = array('meta_value' => $query_args['order']);
    }
    return $query_args;
}

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and works.

I did as @LoicTheAztec suggested and created custom metadata for the shipping last name. I then was able to sort the column with the following code:
function hpos_args( $query_vars ) {

    $query_vars['meta_query'] = array(array(    'key' => '_sorting_name' ));
    $query_vars['orderby'] = array('meta_value' => $query_vars['order']);

    return $query_vars;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_query_args', 'hpos_args', 10, 1 );

I was having issues using the key name _shipping_last_name so went with _sorting_name.
