Filter by vendor( wcfm) in the woocommerce orders table
I’ve been trying to add a new filter to my WooCommerce orders table based on vendors. I successfully connected the WCFM vendors list to a dropdown menu, allowing users to select a vendor. However, when a vendor is selected, it does not display the related orders and instead shows a message stating that no orders are available. I believe the query is correct since it does show the list of orders.
Thank you for your assistance!
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wcfm_filter_orders_by_store' );

function wcfm_filter_orders_by_store( $query ) {
    global $typenow;

    if ( 'shop_order' === $typenow && is_admin() && isset( $_GET['wcfm_store_filter'] ) && ! empty( $_GET['wcfm_store_filter'] ) ) {
        $store_id = intval( $_GET['wcfm_store_filter'] );

        $meta_query = array(
            array(
                'key'     => '_vendor_id', // Assuming this is the correct meta key
                'value'   => $store_id,
                'compare' => '=',
            )
        );

        $existing_meta_query = $query->get( 'meta_query' );

        if ( is_array( $existing_meta_query ) ) {
            $meta_query = array_merge( $existing_meta_query, $meta_query );
        }

        $query->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );
    }
}



Maybe this is because High performance order storage is now enabled by default in WooCommerce, so pre_get_postsdoesn't work with it as in this case orders use custom database tables. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/77366037/3730754 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/78410861/3730754
